# Best practice for validating JSON requests with Yesod

Tags: json, rest, haskell, yesod

I am writing JSON RESTFul service with Yesod and need to implement requests validation.
I cannot use Yesod.Form for it because of the service accepts JSON. I like the way [scalaz validation](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html) uses but I didn't find any approach like this in Haskell.

Is there a best practice to implement validation which would allow to answer with structured errors messages, something like this:

### Request

```
{
    "birthDate": "2017.07.14",
    "count": "three",
    "kind": "baz",
    "entity": {
        "id": -1
    }
}
```

### Response

```
{
    "errors": {
        "birthDate": "Date should be less than 2014.05.25", // current date
        "count": "should be a number",
        "kind": "must be one of [foo, bar]",
        "entity": {
            "id": "Entity with id -1 not found"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [digestive-functors-aeson](https://github.com/ocharles/digestive-functors-aeson) library that utilizes `Text.Digestive.Form` and allows to write expressive validation rules. Here is a gist from its [tests](https://github.com/ocharles/digestive-functors-aeson/blob/master/test/Tests.hs):

```
pokeForm :: Monad m => Form Text m Pokemon
pokeForm = Pokemon <$> "name" .: nonEmptyText
                   <*> "number" .: parseInteger
  where
    nonEmptyText = check "Name cannot be empty" (not . T.null) $
                     text Nothing

testPokedexFailHead =
    let (v, r) = runIdentity $ digestJSON pokedexForm json
    in testGroup "Submit pokedex with a single invalid item"
         [ testCase "Failed validation" $ r @?= Nothing
         , testCase "jsonErrors shows correct errors" $ jsonErrors v @?= errors
         ]
  where
    (Just json) = decode "{\"pokemon\":[{\"name\":\"\"}]}"
    (Just errors) = decode "{\"pokemon\":[{\"name\":\"Name cannot be empty\"}]}"
```

As you can see the library can produces pretty verbose errors which are labeled with field names which failed validation.

Comment: Worth mentioning: `digestive-functors-aeson` is still being maintained but is no longer under development. Also IMHO `digestive-functors` isn't great for validating JSON in the first place. Currently looking for another solution. `forma` looks interesting.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend using aeson's native parsing abilities for this, which will simultaneously parse the incoming JSON and convert it into a Haskell data structure.

Comment: Unfortunately Aeson is not able to produce verbose errors containing which field failed and why. But I got your point: there is no best practice for validating JSON in yesod, feel free to use external solutions.